# How to use codeblocks in itemtemplates

Tags: asp.net, eval, itemtemplate

I have a gridview with several BoundField. Their datafield is set statistically but I have one field that requires an eval to bind to a field dynamically. As BoundField doesn't support Eval, I've added one TemplateField. Here's an example:

```
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:Resource, Type%>" SortExpression="Description">
                                            <ItemStyle CssClass="gridColumn_Header" />
                                            <HeaderStyle CssClass="gridColumn_Header" />
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Literal Text='<%# Eval('StreetType.Description') %>'/>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
```

However, I'm getting an error saying that code blocks aren't supported in this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that codeblocks aren't allowed inside `<asp: runat="server">`, which is odd. The grid is nested inside several panel and update panels, all of which requires runat to get a reference in codebehind.

Although I found the answer to my question, I'm left without a solution.

Comment: Have you tried using double quotes for Eval("StreetType.Description") ?

Answer (score 0):

```
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:Resource, Type%>" SortExpression="Description">
                                        <ItemStyle CssClass="gridColumn_Header" />
                                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="gridColumn_Header" />
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:Literal Text='<%# Eval("StreetType.Description") %>'/>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Eval Should have double qoutes